# Why is my regex pattern collecting more than I am expecting?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am trying to create a regex pattern to get the email address only after the word "Sender".

Below is example input:

```
Recip: fhavor@gmail.com
Subject: Report results (Gd)
Headers: Received: from daem.com (unknown [127.1.1.1])
Date: Sat, 13 Feb 2021 13:11:42 +0000 (GMT)
From: Tavon Lo <lt35@gmail.com>
Recip: fhavor2@gmail.com
Subject: Report results (Gd1)
Headers: Received: from daem2.com (unknown [127.1.1.1])
Date: Sat, 14 Feb 2021 13:11:42 +0000 (GMT)
From: Tavon Lo <lt36@gmail.com>
Sender: lt36@gmail.com
Recipient: hi@gmail.com
```

**So, the only email address that should be in the output is lt36@gmail.com**

Below is my regex pattern:

```
(?m)^Sender:([^<>@]+@[^<>]+)
```

This matches the following:

```
lt36@gmail.com
Recipient: hi@gmail.com
```

See regex demo https://regex101.com/r/qRLrAW/1

I only want lt36@gmail.com. I am new to regex patterns so this is probably an easy fix but I have been stuck. Any ideas or suggestions as how to fix the regex pattern to accommodate my goal?

Comment: Use `(?m)^Sender:([^<>@]+@[^<>\n]+)`

Comment: If you don't need to validate that the email is valid then just capture everything after `Sender: ` like so `(?<=Sender: ).*`. Just make sure the DOTALL modifier is not enabled. https://regex101.com/r/8TLtKt/1

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
(?m)^Sender:[^\S\r\n]*([^<>@\n\r]+@[^<>\n\r]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7tljJi/1).

*Details*:

- `(?m)^` - start of a line
- `Sender:` - a literal string
- `[^\S\r\n]*` - zero or more whitespaces other than CR and LF
- `([^<>@\n\r]+@[^<>\n\r]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than `<`, `>`, `@`, CR and LF, `@` and one or more chars other than `<`, `>`, `@`, CR and LF.

Comment: you truly are a regex expert. I have learnt so much from your posts. Thanks for providing the details on the regex solution

Comment: @JoeFerndz BTW, do you need to get the single, first match in the text, or are using it with `re.findall` to collect all matches?

Comment: This was not my question but was looking at this to get all the items. So its for re.findall() (would be interesting to see results for both one line single result or one line multiple results. I think for multiple results, I can use re.findall(). For single result, I was going to do [0])

Comment: @JoeFerndz I see. Well, to get a single match, `re.search` is recommended. Like `m = re.search(pattern, text)` and then `if m: print(m.group(1))`

Answer (score 1):

It's because `[^<>]+` matches `\n` as well, so it will go over the end of the line to the next line.

You need to add a `\n` to your negated character classes, as [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) did in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66230559/14349868).

Answer (score 1):

The catch here is that you have to exclude matching newlines by adding them to the negated character class.

You can also turn the match into a positive lookbehind:

```
(?m)(?<=^Sender: )[^<>@\n\r]+@[^<>\r\n]+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DPeQOJ/1)

If the email address can also not contain spaces, you can use `\s` instead of `\r\n`

```
(?m)(?<=^Sender: )[^<>@\s]+@[^<>\s]+
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?m)` Inline modifier for multiline
- `(?<=^Sender: )` Assert Sender: at the left at the start of the string
- `[^<>@\s]+@[^<>\s]+` Match an email like pattern excluding spaces and newlines

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/t02n4b/1)

Just as an example using the [PyPi regex module](https://tio.run/##pZJdT8IwFIbv@ytOdrUpIXSgJg0iF4oSwQuGVwySsh1YdWuXrqD@@tmZJUhmTMTTm5P0PV9P3vzDJEp2y1JkudIGNG7xnZCcG4NawjVox73JvFWAMkbNFqswCHUol2fh42LVHwzDYnk@rLIqcQgpbInrzDASOYNNwvdKD7cZF2k7UlkoHQLfwgl26xeMDIMZ1tOLXWoKcO9jryF@QG5XKCpxhGKPsR2gVQYxx6zqDu5Ovkr1JmFB/as2rd6y2eaWG2QQcNMC2oURrsHv@NTmjFLW8@G8Y8NuMJ03a0d2HoO5vUrCREE/Nd2Lw3mDhv6Ig38aCPo3Ev6JKHr/R3H5G4raQHCs@5mYQGlRJOKgczxCMm6iBCuDfZm0vREy5mnq1l5tQdGqf6bPk/l4Mn6680iuhTRuXeqV5Sc) you might also use `\K` to get the match only.

Answer (score 0):

I think this expression is will useful for where first part will remove Sender expression where . and + will select email area

```
(?<=Sender: ).+
```